# Using Karabiner to modify keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, keybindings, karabiner

I have two bluetooth keyboards that I use with my MacBookPro - Apple's Magic Keyboard with Number Pad and the Rii RK801 Wireless Bluetooth Keyboard. The issue that I have is that the Home and End keys are operating differently on each keyboard. While it is not a problem on the Mac, when using Windows via Remote Desktop it causes issues. as the Rii RK801 Wireless Bluetooth Keyboard docks the window I am working on to the left (home) or right (end) of the screen and shows me other windows which can be tiled on the other half of the screen.

Using the KeyCodes app and the Karabiner-EventViewer, it was determined that the keyboards are sending different signals for the keypresses:

| Key Pressed | Apple MagicKeyboard | Rii RK801 Wireless BT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [HOME] | **KeyCode App** Unicode: 63273 / 0xf729 Keys: ⬉ Keycode: 115 / 0x73 **Karabiner-EventViewer:** [ { "type": "down", "name": {"key_code":"home"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "74 (0x004a)", "misc": "" }, { "type": "up", "name": {"key_code":"home"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "74 (0x004a)", "misc": "" } ] | **KeyCode App** Unicode: 63234 / 0xf702 Keys: ⌘← Keycode: 123 / 0x7b **Karabiner-EventViewer:** [ { "type": "down", "name": {"key_code":"left_command"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "227 (0x00e3)", "misc": "flags left_command" }, { "type": "down", "name": {"key_code":"left_arrow"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "80 (0x0050)", "misc": "flags left_command" }, { "type": "up", "name": {"key_code":"left_arrow"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "80 (0x0050)", "misc": "flags left_command" }, { "type": "up", "name": {"key_code":"left_command"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "227 (0x00e3)", "misc": "" } ] |
| [END] | **KeyCode App** Unicode: 63275 / 0xf72b Keys: ➘ Keycode: 119 / 0x77 **Karabiner-EventViewer:** [ { "type": "down", "name": {"key_code":"end"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "77 (0x004d)", "misc": "" }, { "type": "up", "name": {"key_code":"end"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "77 (0x004d)", "misc": "" }, ] | **KeyCode App** Unicode: 63235 / 0xf703 Keys: ⌘→ Keycode: 124 / 0x7c **Karabiner-EventViewer:** [ { "type": "down", "name": {"key_code":"left_command"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "227 (0x00e3)", "misc": "flags left_command" }, { "type": "down", "name": {"key_code":"right_arrow"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "79 (0x004f)", "misc": "flags left_command" }, { "type": "up", "name": {"key_code":"right_arrow"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "79 (0x004f)", "misc": "flags left_command" }, { "type": "up", "name": {"key_code":"left_command"}, "usagePage": "7 (0x0007)", "usage": "227 (0x00e3)", "misc": "" } ] |

How would I be able to get the Rii RK801 to match the Apple Magic Keyboard? As it seems that the Rii RK801 is actually sending multiple keypresses with the [Home] and [End] buttons instead of a single keypress that the MagicKeyboard is sending.

Thank you in advance for your guidance on this issue.